# Data Transfer Pausing to 0bytes/s and then going back up

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

I have these two [MNPA19-XTR MELLANOX 10GB ETHERNET NETWORK INTERFACE CARD](https://www.ebay.com/itm/282378634053)

My two Servers
1. Dell PowerEdge R900
2. Dell PowerEdge T300

i am copying data from R900 to T300

These two servers are connected using those Network Cards Peer to Peer

When i start the data move, it goes up to 320MB/s(Approx) and stays there for few 30 seconds and then drops to 0MB/s and wait for 30 seconds or sometime more and then goes back to 320MB/s(Approx.)

It's just cycling between 0 to 320MB/s with those intervals as if it's resting

Before these cards i had Gigabit Ethernet cards and i was able to consistently get 100MB/s without any interruption

***Thank you in Advance for reading my question***

**Server Side Data**

```
V:\Mallanox>iperf3.exe -s -I lab5
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 192.168.100.201, port 57606
[  5] local 192.168.100.205 port 5201 connected to 192.168.100.201 port 57607
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   353 MBytes  2.96 Gbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   287 MBytes  2.41 Gbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   266 MBytes  2.23 Gbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   268 MBytes  2.24 Gbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   267 MBytes  2.24 Gbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   262 MBytes  2.20 Gbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   249 MBytes  2.09 Gbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   254 MBytes  2.13 Gbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   258 MBytes  2.16 Gbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   246 MBytes  2.07 Gbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-11.00  sec   254 MBytes  2.13 Gbits/sec
[  5]  11.00-12.00  sec   247 MBytes  2.07 Gbits/sec
[  5]  12.00-13.00  sec   235 MBytes  1.97 Gbits/sec
[  5]  13.00-14.00  sec   244 MBytes  2.04 Gbits/sec
[  5]  14.00-15.00  sec   230 MBytes  1.93 Gbits/sec
[  5]  15.00-16.00  sec   239 MBytes  2.00 Gbits/sec
[  5]  16.00-17.00  sec   229 MBytes  1.92 Gbits/sec
[  5]  17.00-18.00  sec   251 MBytes  2.11 Gbits/sec
[  5]  18.00-19.00  sec   251 MBytes  2.10 Gbits/sec
[  5]  19.00-20.00  sec   283 MBytes  2.38 Gbits/sec
[  5]  20.00-21.00  sec   319 MBytes  2.68 Gbits/sec
[  5]  21.00-22.00  sec   320 MBytes  2.68 Gbits/sec
[  5]  22.00-23.00  sec   318 MBytes  2.67 Gbits/sec
[  5]  23.00-24.00  sec   336 MBytes  2.82 Gbits/sec
[  5]  24.00-25.00  sec   356 MBytes  2.98 Gbits/sec
[  5]  25.00-26.00  sec   380 MBytes  3.18 Gbits/sec
[  5]  26.00-27.00  sec   407 MBytes  3.42 Gbits/sec
[  5]  27.00-28.00  sec   420 MBytes  3.52 Gbits/sec
[  5]  28.00-29.00  sec   411 MBytes  3.45 Gbits/sec
[  5]  29.00-30.00  sec   405 MBytes  3.39 Gbits/sec
[  5]  30.00-31.00  sec   395 MBytes  3.31 Gbits/sec
[  5]  31.00-32.00  sec   397 MBytes  3.33 Gbits/sec
[  5]  32.00-33.00  sec   402 MBytes  3.37 Gbits/sec
[  5]  33.00-34.00  sec   411 MBytes  3.45 Gbits/sec
[  5]  34.00-35.00  sec   423 MBytes  3.55 Gbits/sec
[  5]  35.00-36.00  sec   410 MBytes  3.44 Gbits/sec
[  5]  36.00-37.00  sec   420 MBytes  3.53 Gbits/sec
[  5]  37.00-38.00  sec   356 MBytes  2.99 Gbits/sec
[  5]  38.00-39.00  sec   342 MBytes  2.86 Gbits/sec
[  5]  39.00-40.00  sec   308 MBytes  2.59 Gbits/sec
[  5]  40.00-41.00  sec   326 MBytes  2.73 Gbits/sec
[  5]  41.00-42.00  sec   326 MBytes  2.74 Gbits/sec
[  5]  42.00-43.00  sec   310 MBytes  2.60 Gbits/sec
[  5]  43.00-44.00  sec   329 MBytes  2.76 Gbits/sec
[  5]  44.00-45.00  sec   324 MBytes  2.71 Gbits/sec
[  5]  45.00-46.00  sec   306 MBytes  2.57 Gbits/sec
[  5]  46.00-47.00  sec   293 MBytes  2.45 Gbits/sec
[  5]  47.00-48.00  sec   297 MBytes  2.50 Gbits/sec
[  5]  48.00-49.00  sec   303 MBytes  2.53 Gbits/sec
[  5]  49.00-50.00  sec   306 MBytes  2.57 Gbits/sec
[  5]  50.00-51.00  sec   325 MBytes  2.72 Gbits/sec
[  5]  51.00-52.00  sec   299 MBytes  2.51 Gbits/sec
[  5]  52.00-53.00  sec   321 MBytes  2.69 Gbits/sec
[  5]  53.00-54.00  sec   293 MBytes  2.46 Gbits/sec
[  5]  54.00-55.00  sec   344 MBytes  2.88 Gbits/sec
[  5]  55.00-56.00  sec   390 MBytes  3.27 Gbits/sec
[  5]  56.00-57.00  sec   397 MBytes  3.33 Gbits/sec
[  5]  57.00-58.00  sec   396 MBytes  3.32 Gbits/sec
[  5]  58.00-59.00  sec   398 MBytes  3.34 Gbits/sec
[  5]  59.00-60.00  sec   398 MBytes  3.33 Gbits/sec
[  5]  60.00-60.05  sec  17.6 MBytes  3.05 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-60.05  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-60.05  sec  18.9 GBytes  2.71 Gbits/sec                  receiver
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Client Side Data**

```
M:\Mallanox>iperf3.exe -c 192.168.100.205 -t 60 -i 1 -w 2M
Connecting to host 192.168.100.205, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.100.201 port 57607 connected to 192.168.100.205 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   372 MBytes  3.12 Gbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   283 MBytes  2.37 Gbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   266 MBytes  2.23 Gbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   264 MBytes  2.22 Gbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   269 MBytes  2.26 Gbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   263 MBytes  2.20 Gbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   249 MBytes  2.09 Gbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   255 MBytes  2.13 Gbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   256 MBytes  2.15 Gbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   248 MBytes  2.08 Gbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.01  sec   253 MBytes  2.12 Gbits/sec
[  4]  11.01-12.00  sec   247 MBytes  2.08 Gbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   236 MBytes  1.98 Gbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec   241 MBytes  2.02 Gbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec   230 MBytes  1.93 Gbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec   243 MBytes  2.03 Gbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec   226 MBytes  1.89 Gbits/sec
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec   254 MBytes  2.14 Gbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-19.00  sec   246 MBytes  2.06 Gbits/sec
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec   290 MBytes  2.44 Gbits/sec
[  4]  20.00-21.00  sec   315 MBytes  2.64 Gbits/sec
[  4]  21.00-22.00  sec   320 MBytes  2.68 Gbits/sec
[  4]  22.00-23.00  sec   320 MBytes  2.69 Gbits/sec
[  4]  23.00-24.00  sec   336 MBytes  2.82 Gbits/sec
[  4]  24.00-25.00  sec   356 MBytes  2.99 Gbits/sec
[  4]  25.00-26.00  sec   380 MBytes  3.18 Gbits/sec
[  4]  26.00-27.00  sec   409 MBytes  3.43 Gbits/sec
[  4]  27.00-28.00  sec   420 MBytes  3.52 Gbits/sec
[  4]  28.00-29.00  sec   412 MBytes  3.45 Gbits/sec
[  4]  29.00-30.00  sec   404 MBytes  3.39 Gbits/sec
[  4]  30.00-31.00  sec   394 MBytes  3.30 Gbits/sec
[  4]  31.00-32.00  sec   398 MBytes  3.34 Gbits/sec
[  4]  32.00-33.00  sec   400 MBytes  3.35 Gbits/sec
[  4]  33.00-34.00  sec   414 MBytes  3.47 Gbits/sec
[  4]  34.00-35.00  sec   423 MBytes  3.54 Gbits/sec
[  4]  35.00-36.00  sec   408 MBytes  3.42 Gbits/sec
[  4]  36.00-37.00  sec   421 MBytes  3.53 Gbits/sec
[  4]  37.00-38.00  sec   355 MBytes  2.98 Gbits/sec
[  4]  38.00-39.00  sec   340 MBytes  2.85 Gbits/sec
[  4]  39.00-40.00  sec   311 MBytes  2.61 Gbits/sec
[  4]  40.00-41.00  sec   324 MBytes  2.72 Gbits/sec
[  4]  41.00-42.00  sec   327 MBytes  2.74 Gbits/sec
[  4]  42.00-43.00  sec   309 MBytes  2.59 Gbits/sec
[  4]  43.00-44.00  sec   331 MBytes  2.78 Gbits/sec
[  4]  44.00-45.00  sec   323 MBytes  2.71 Gbits/sec
[  4]  45.00-46.00  sec   305 MBytes  2.56 Gbits/sec
[  4]  46.00-47.00  sec   294 MBytes  2.46 Gbits/sec
[  4]  47.00-48.00  sec   298 MBytes  2.49 Gbits/sec
[  4]  48.00-49.00  sec   297 MBytes  2.49 Gbits/sec
[  4]  49.00-50.00  sec   311 MBytes  2.61 Gbits/sec
[  4]  50.00-51.00  sec   320 MBytes  2.69 Gbits/sec
[  4]  51.00-52.00  sec   305 MBytes  2.56 Gbits/sec
[  4]  52.00-53.00  sec   318 MBytes  2.66 Gbits/sec
[  4]  53.00-54.00  sec   296 MBytes  2.48 Gbits/sec
[  4]  54.00-55.00  sec   341 MBytes  2.86 Gbits/sec
[  4]  55.00-56.00  sec   393 MBytes  3.30 Gbits/sec
[  4]  56.00-57.00  sec   398 MBytes  3.34 Gbits/sec
[  4]  57.00-58.00  sec   397 MBytes  3.33 Gbits/sec
[  4]  58.00-59.00  sec   399 MBytes  3.35 Gbits/sec
[  4]  59.00-60.00  sec   397 MBytes  3.33 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-60.00  sec  19.0 GBytes  2.71 Gbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-60.00  sec  18.9 GBytes  2.71 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Please quantify this. Run iperf between the two machines and edit your question to include the full results. Run iperf in server mode on one machine: `iperf -s -i 1 -w 2M`. Run iperf in client mode on the other machine: `iperf -c <IPofIPerfServerMachine> -t 60 -i 1 -w 2M`. This does a 60-second test while reporting thruput every second. Note that iperf defaults to an "upload" test; it *sends* data from the client to the server. So keep that in mind when picking which machine is the client and the server, so your iperf traffic is going in the same direction as your original test.

Comment: @Spiff thank you for teaching me about iperf. i wasn't aware of this tool i have updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the iperf results and the more detailed problem description. Huh, so it seems the dropouts don't happen with iperf with these settings. These iperf results make it look like the machine just isn't capable of saturating a 10GbE link, so it just goes 2-3 gigabits/sec. Your previous data point of 320 MebiBytes/sec is equivalent to the 2.7 gigabits/second that iperf reported here. What software/protocol were you using for your original data point? Was it just a file copy via Windows' built-in SMB file sharing?

Comment: Freefilesync to back to another server I just bought these cards so want to find out if it’s the cards or something else

Comment: My concern is if it’s hardware or OS I been contemplating if installing Ubuntu on both servers and then running VMware workstations would give me better performance or worse

Comment: Actually tried direct copy as well same speed and same pause too initially I was thinking maybe it’s those stupid windows update or something or windows defender disabled all that still same result

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It's not MTU. TCP/IP over Ethernet is 94% efficient with standard 1500 byte MTUs. So you can get 9.4 gigabits/sec from 10GbE without switching to nonstandard jumbo frames.